# Following the value of a function in a function

Tags: ida

So I have a function called _invoke_watson, and one line of this function is:

Call IsDebuggerPresent

Now how do I follow the value of IsDebuggerPresent?

Another general question , if I'm completely stuck at a point , is it ok to ask on stack exchange on how to progress. As if I have no clue and I ask someone else there is blah blah , what steps do I take?

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of IsDebuggerPresent"? The API itself or the output?

Answer (score 1):

What debugger / disassembler are you using? Please include this in your question, but assuming its IDA, double click on "IsDebuggerPresent", or if its x32dbg / x64dbg you can right click on it -> follow in disassembly -> IsDebuggerPresent

EDIT:

I see you tagged IDA, so what you need to do is double click on IsDebuggerPresent

Comment: So if I double click IsDebuggerPresent , it will show me it's value , if there isn't a debugger it should be zero , and if not any other number.

Comment: What do you mean value? The disassembly of the function? Yes, that is what should happen.